# Compare correlations between the same variables measured with two methods

Tags: correlation, paired-data, agreement-statistics

I have measured the same variables (quantities of microorganism by 16S sequencing) on some samples in two ways, A (in the stools) and B (from an intestinal biopsy). I am trying to do two things:

1. Compare if A is similar to B: That quantifying in the stools is as reliable as looking to the intestinal
2. Compare if some samples, based on the location of the biopsy,  from the colon (1, 2, 3) are more similar to A than samples (4, 5, 6) from the ileum are to A, the stools.

My hypothesis is that the correlation between A and B for the same variable should be 1, otherwise the differences might be due to the method or noise.

In another question I found a [link to material](http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/CompareCorrCoeff.pdf) about how to compare correlation coefficients, which I can use to compare between A and B each variable. But how can I aggregate each variable to see if globally the samples are similar to B or less similar between them?

In agreement statistics language, I have two raters (the two methods of sequencing) and N natural continous $[0, \infty)$ variables (the number of microorganism identified) for some J samples (the patients). I want to compare if for some group of samples (the location, the condition) the agreement between raters is different than for other groups.